# How to Take Two Different Full Backup From Mariadb With Restic

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I have mariadb server. I take my backups with mariadb-backup tool and restic. I have a backup strategy. According to it, i need to take a full backup on every sunday at 00.00 am and need to take incremental backup in every 10 minutes. And i have to keep at least two week backups. This need requires multiple full backups but restic doesn't support sequential full backups. It takes one full backup and the other ones become incremental. How can i take two different full backup with restic on mariadb using mariadb-backup tool?

Comment: I'd complement this by using binary logs as a point in time recovery. See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322313/mariadb-mysql-point-in-time-recovery), and keep in mind binary log positions are saves with `mariadb-backup`. Also always test a restoration of your backups. I don't know about `restic` to answer the question however.